# Akka Remoting for a grid server application

Tags: scala, akka

Our application has a server-node that delegates work to numerous worker-nodes that are remote actors. This application is expected to scale by increasing the number of worker nodes.

We are using Akka 1.3-RC4, and bet doing something wrong because we notice the following:

1> New sockets are opened when tasks are being sent to worker nodes from server. The sockets close once the task completes. Is there a benefit over / reason why the sockets are not always kept open? Is there any conf that we need to tweak?

2> When we list the number of file descriptors opened by the server process PID, the number shoots up proportional to the number of sockets open(totally expected). The goal of this application is to scale to huge (global) compute-farms however, once the limit of file descriptors is reached the server-node can't open sockets for any more worker-nodes. Wonder if we should change the design and approach in another way.

Another thing we are actively considering is to move to Akka 2 however, not sure if it has a better way to solve this kind of problem.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can increase the read timeout for the connections, to keep them open longer
2. You should switch to 1.3-RC6 as it fixes some remote-related performance issues
3. Akka 2.0 be default resuses inbound connections for outbound messages, leading to much better scalability for your use-case

Hope this helps,

Cheers,
√

Comment: Thanks Victor. Trying out RC6 right away, but i think we'll move to 2.0 eventually(code migration is taking some time)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!

Regarding point 1 of your advice above:

Even though I have:    \n"connection-timeout = 1000 # Number in time-unit"\n  in the remote/server section of my akka.conf, the sockets are getting opened and closed almost immediately (within a second or so of the message being sent); i.e. the sockets are not staying open for 1000 seconds as expected. I got this same behavior using both Akka 1.2 and Akka 1.3-RC6. Could you please give us a pointer about what I may be doing incorrectly?

Comment: Regarding no1, I said "read timeout": read-timeout = 120                   # Number in time-unit.